# Rewrite url for friendly seo

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Does anyone know a working way for this to be done?

Rewrite url `http://example.com/index.php?page=the-page` to `http://example.com/the-page`

I hope that someone know how this is done, can't find a working rewriterule.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it here.. 
So if anyone need this too :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```